# Unable to understand Apple Crash Log with -[UIApplication _cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:]

Tags: swift

I'm unable to understand this crash log from Apple. I have been a few times rejected because of this. They are complaining it's occurred on ipad running latest software 10.3.1. When we double check with on ipad simulator, it's running without crashes.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1848b2fd8 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x183314538 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1848b2eac +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
3   Foundation                      0x18534a710 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112
4   UIKit                           0x18ac57454 -[UIApplication _cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:] + 196
5   UIKit                           0x18ac57514 -[UIApplication _systemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:] + 24
6   UIKit                           0x18acb07a0 +[UIWindow _synchronizedDrawingFence] + 116
7   UIKit                           0x18ae6e150 +[_UIKeyboardChangedInformation informationForKeyboardUp:withIAV:] + 104
8   UIKit                           0x18b1678d4 -[_UIRemoteKeyboards prepareToMoveKeyboard:withIAV:showing:forScreen:] + 464
9   UIKit                           0x18aa9fc04 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 820
10  UIKit                           0x18aabccf4 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _restoreInputViewsWithId:animated:] + 584
11  UIKit                           0x18ad4fd64 -[UIViewController _restoreInputViewsForPresentation] + 280
12  UIKit                           0x18ad2ae3c -[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState] + 1560
13  UIKit                           0x18ad290f8 -[UIPresentationController _dismissWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:] + 764
14  UIKit                           0x18ad4f8c0 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithAnimationController:interactionController:completion:] + 464
15  UIKit                           0x18ab04cd4 -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 600
16  UIKit                           0x18aaacb6c -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 1144
17  UIKit                           0x18aaac94c -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 600
18  UIKit                           0x18ad4eb68 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 524
19  UIKit                           0x18aaac6c0 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 152
20  newapp                          0x100115628 0x1000b0000 + 415272
21  newapp                          0x1001159e8 0x1000b0000 + 416232
22  CFNetwork                       0x184ebc1fc __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
23  CFNetwork                       0x184ed3ef8 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 148
24  Foundation                      0x185381804 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
25  Foundation                      0x1852c6760 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96
26  Foundation                      0x1852b6b18 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 612
27  Foundation                      0x185383ba0 __NSOQSchedule_f + 228
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x18376a9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x183778ad4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x18376e2cc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 884
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x18377aa50 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 540
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x18377a7d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1839731d0 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x183972d7c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018388f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018388f09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184860e88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018485eadc __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018478ed94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001861f8074 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKit                           0x000000018aa40130 UIApplicationMain + 208
7   newapp                          0x000000010022f390 0x1000b0000 + 1569680
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018379d59c start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018388f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018388f09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184860e88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018485eadc __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018478ed94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x00000001852a8d64 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001852c9b34 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b3ca5f8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x00000001853a62c8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018397575c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018397566c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183972d84 thread_start + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001838ada88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183973274 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183972d7c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFStream.LegacyThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018388f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018388f09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184860e88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018485eadc __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018478ed94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018486e78c _legacyStreamRunLoop_workThread + 268
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018397575c _pthread_body + 240
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018397566c _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183972d84 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018388f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018388f09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184860e88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018485eadc __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018478ed94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000184f9aca4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404
6   Foundation                      0x00000001853a62c8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018397575c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018397566c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183972d84 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x170031360 :: NSOperation 0x17024ab30 (QOS: DEFAULT)
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001838ad014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183977334 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001838219c4 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001832ed1b0 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183306c04 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183314820 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001833035d4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183303640 std::terminate() + 60
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018376a9b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183778ad4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018376e2cc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 884
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018377aa50 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 540
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018377a7d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001839731d0 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183972d7c start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Do you have any further information (e.g., exception name, etc) or this is it?

Comment: From where I stand, it looks like a crash *after* you finish uploading a file... makes sense?

Comment: Make sure you are dismissing the view controller from the main queue and not a background queue.

Comment: Hi Guys, here is the full log. [https://pastebin.com/4Qs9A9Ly](https://pastebin.com/4Qs9A9Ly) This occur after sending a submit request to http address. and its only happen on ipad when being tested by apple. I can't replicate on my iPhone and not on ipad simulator. any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone App Crash with error \[UIApplication \_cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695328/iphone-app-crash-with-error-uiapplication-cachedsystemanimationfencecreatingif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log clearly shows the problem happens on a background thread. You need to perform UI actions on the main queue. Use `DispatchQueue.main.async` to dismiss the view controller.

Comment: Looks like you nailed it! The crash indeed happens on thread #5 ;-)

Comment: That was really helpful. Waiting for another review now. Is there any reason why it didn't crash on my device and also simulator ? Slow network ? I can't believe they rejected few times already because of this. Thank you.